# Optimization of query with counts of distinct column based on value of other column

Tags: sql, sql-server

There must be a better way to write this, but I'm just not sure what that is. Basically I'm trying to count the distinct values from one column where a condition is met in a separate column. I found this [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11853065/trying-to-count-distinct-values-of-a-field-based-on-value-of-a-different-field), but am not sure how to apply it here.

Here is the query, I am using SQL Server 2008R2

```
SELECT lot,
    (SELECT COUNT(DISTINCT d.pid) FROM invdet d WHERE upk = 0 and d.lot = [invdet].lot) as noUpk,
    (SELECT COUNT(DISTINCT d.pid) FROM invdet d WHERE upk = 1 and d.lot = [invdet].lot) as isUpk
FROM invdet
WHERE ([status] in ('PQ','P2','FA','F2','BH','RL','SC','LD','PS'))
GROUP BY lot
HAVING COUNT(CASE WHEN invdet.upk = 1 THEN 1 ELSE null END) > 0
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use the fact that `COUNT DISTINCT` does not count NULLs to your advantage. In order to examine all the rows, create a `WHERE EXISTS` clause instead of limiting your result set to those statuses:

```
SELECT lot,
    COUNT(DISTINCT (CASE WHEN upk = 0 THEN pid ELSE NULL END)) as noUpk
    COUNT(DISTINCT (CASE WHEN upk = 1 THEN pid ELSE NULL END)) as isUpk
FROM invdet q
WHERE EXISTS
(
    SELECT 1 
    FROM invdet i 
    WHERE i.[status] in ('PQ','P2','FA','F2','BH','RL','SC','LD','PS')
    AND i.lot = q.lot
)
GROUP BY lot
HAVING COUNT(CASE WHEN upk = 1 THEN 1 ELSE null END) > 0
```

---

You can also effectively move the `HAVING` clause into a `WHERE EXISTS` clause as well, which may be faster, resulting in:

```
SELECT lot,
    COUNT(DISTINCT (CASE WHEN upk = 0 THEN pid ELSE NULL END)) as noUpk
    COUNT(DISTINCT (CASE WHEN upk = 1 THEN pid ELSE NULL END)) as isUpk
FROM invdet q
WHERE EXISTS
(
    SELECT 1 
    FROM invdet i 
    WHERE i.[status] in ('PQ','P2','FA','F2','BH','RL','SC','LD','PS')
    AND i.lot = q.lot
)
WHERE EXISTS
(
    SELECT 1 
    FROM invdet i 
    WHERE i.upk = 1 
    AND i.lot = q.lot
)
GROUP BY lot
```

Comment: Thanks, but I do need to consider all the rows, regardless of status. Some background: A lot is a parent to the details contained in the invdet table. I want to examine all the details for any lot with at least one detail in the statuses listed.

Comment: @user1803504 Ok I have edited my answer to take this into account.